# Grafana - How to "combine" two different dashboards (JSON)?

Tags: grafana

Small question regarding Grafana dashboards please.

I have the JSON of a first dashboard, the dashboard looks great, very happy.

There is also a second dashboard for some other metrics. Also very cool, no problem at all.

The two dashboards are very well made, and provide important information. Hence, on a daily basis, we open two browser tabs to display the two dashboards.

I was wondering, how to combine the two dashboards into one please?

Very naive, I thought: "Let's copy the content of the second JSON and paste it inside the first JSON"

And it is not working at all...

May I ask, what is the correct way to combine dashboards please?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm hoping this question gets answered as I'm curious myself.

Comment: It is little old question but it may help anyone else who is searching for the solution. Below github repo have a tool and steps which merge two dashboard. https://github.com/TheProjectAurora/grafana/blob/main/README.md